# TFS deploy error destination not reachable

Tags: msdeploy

We have 1 new DEV and 1 new QA server that I am configuring for automated deploys. I got the DEV deploys working. My problem is that the deploy to QA is giving me the below error.

Our build server contains the controller and drop folder. The error occurs when the Invoke deploy command is issued. I have ensured that the Web Management service is running on the web servers.

What could be causing the follow error message?

```
Error Code: ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE
More Information: Could not connect to the destination computer ("myWebServer"). 
On the destination computer, make sure that Web Deploy is installed and that the 
required process ("Web Deployment Agent Service") is started.
Error: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
Error count: 1.
```

Here is my deploy command:

```
\\myBuildServer\Builds\MyApp - Deploy to QA\myApp - Deploy to QA_20120827.1\_PublishedWebsites\AppName.UI.Web_Package\Appname.UI.Web.deploy.cmd /M:http://myWebAddress/MsDeployAgentService/ /U:myDomain\tfsUID /P:MyPassword "-setParam:name='IIS Web Application Name',value='MyWebAppName'" /Y
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're on IIS 7, ensure that WMSvc is installed (add or turn on Windows features) running, that it is configured correctly and enabled in IIS Manager under "Management Service" and that port 8172 is open - try telnet-ing into it.

If IIS 6, install the Web Deploy agent.

For IIS 7 using WMSvc, you should use `http://svr:8172/MsDeploy.axd` and for MsDepSvc you are already using the right URL (see your /M param).

I've found the whole remote publishing to be a total ballache.

Comment: Telnet is always our savior!

Answer (score 0):

When you install Web Deploy, make sure to select Custom and check all components. This is what solved the issue for me.

[image]

Source: [Could not reach the Web Deploy endpoint on the specified virtual machine](https://port135.com/2019/07/29/could-not-reach-the-web-deploy-endpoint-specified-virtual-machine/)